# AWS MediaConvert job settings unit tests

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, aws-sdk, aws-media-convert

I am using `CreateJobCommandInput`, `CreateJobCommand`, `MediaConvertClient` from `@aws-sdk/client-mediaconvert` to submit MediaConvert job. `CreateJobCommandInput` contains a lot of different parameters. I would like to check if those parameters are valid using some sort of unit tests. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your message.  AWS MediaConvert validates job settings upon submittal. Unit testing (individual feature testing) is not supported today.

However, you can save a collection of validated output settings as an output preset which can be re-used and stacked (combined) on future jobs.  You can test, validate and accumulate collections of output settings in this way.

Additional tips:
[a] when testing settings, you can use the 'input clipping' function to convert just 30s of content for a quicker result on your tests.

[b] All 'create job' calls will have an API log record which you can retrieve via AWS CloudTrail.  Jobs which execute will also get a log entry in AWS CloudWatch.

[c] Fronting your S3 destination bucket with a CloudFront distribution will allow you to stream/access your outputs without making the S3 bucket itself public-readable. You can optionally restrict access to the CF distribution in various ways using AWS Web Application Firewall.

You can see the full specification for all available parameters using a command of the form 'aws mediaconvert create-job --generate-cli-skeleton'

Comment: I can find create job events, but there aren't any completion or progression events?

Comment: That is correct.  Job progression and completion are tracked as metadata but they do not emit API events. The status for both can be gotten  in response to either a 'get_job'  call (for a specific job) or a list_jobs call (shows status of all jobs).    You can try these from the ACW CLI or CloudShell prompt. FYI the AWS Console makes a List_jobs call in the background every ~10s or so to update the web display.  

Additionally  there will be a CloudWatch log message (not an API event) with the job completion message or an error message.

Comment: You can query CloudWatch logs with a separate API call, and if you wish, you can have CloudWatch log messages forwarded by a Lambda function to a REST endpoint (such as Slack) or to an SNS topic.

Comment: I cannot find any logs (nor are there any log groups for mediaconvert) in CloudWatch in AWS console, I was however able to create a `aws_cloudwatch_event_rule` & `aws_cloudwatch_event_target` via terraform to send completion event to SQS and somehow it magically works...

Comment: The default log groups is at /aws/events/ElementalMediaConvert.   You can verify this from your AWS CLI or cloudShell prompt by running `aws logs describe-log-groups |grep Convert` .

You can also check logs from the CLI ;  try command:

```L5M=` expr $DS - 300 `; aws logs filter-log-events --log-group-name "/aws/events/ElementalMediaConvert" --start-time $L5M --max-items 50 --filter-pattern "" |grep -i -o -E 'jobId.{60}' ```